# How to disable autoforwarding option in office 365?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365

Im struggling to disable `autoforwarding` option of emails in `office 365`. I wish to remove highlighted autoforwarding option entirely.

[image]

So i followed, https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exovoice/2017/12/07/disable-automatic-forwarding-in-office-365-and-exchange-server-to-prevent-information-leakage/

I logged into office 365 tenant in powershell and executed below commands

```
New-ManagementRole MyBaseOptions-DisableForwarding -Parent MyBaseOptions

Set-ManagementRoleEntry MyBaseOptions-DisableForwarding\Set-Mailbox -RemoveParameter -Parameters DeliverToMailboxAndForward,ForwardingAddress,ForwardingSmtpAddress
```

Then created a new **RoleAssignmentPolicy**  called `"DisabledForwardingRoleAssignmentPolicy"`

```
New-RoleAssignmentPolicy -Name DisabledForwardingRoleAssignmentPolicy -Roles MyBaseOptions-DisableForwarding,MyContactInformation,MyRetentionPolicies,MyMailSubscriptions,MyTextMessaging,MyVoiceMail,MyDistributionGroupMembership,MyDistributionGroups, MyProfileInformation
```

and did what was said in the referenced link. tick only `"MyBaseOptions-DisableForwarding"`

[image]

and assigned to a user

[image]

Waited few hours and see whether the autoforwarding option is vanished for that user.
Its not just the same. it is there as usual. 
What I am missing ? cant figure out. please help me to solve this.

**PS:
Note:**

Apparently i tried with creating a new fresh user and applied my role assignment policy "DisabledForwardingRoleAssignmentPolicy"` and it **worked for the fresh profile**. it will remove autoforwarding for new account.

But **already created old accounts this did not work**., any possibility to force/refresh the policy to old profiles ? Cant understand why it is not applying to old emails.

Thanks in advance for any clue

KR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found out that tt is not something to do with **old profiles** vs **new profiles**. If a user is a **globaladmin in office 365** his/her profile will not be applied above policy. May be its by design. not sure though.
already project in techcommunity.microsoft.com ,

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-365/Why-RoleAssignmentPolicy-not-applied-to-Globaladmins-in-office/m-p/198014#M13363

yet no clear definition, y?